# File system check during boot every time after resizing Ubuntu partitions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, filesystem, gparted

Recently I resized my Ubuntu partitions using `gparted` from a live USB. The problem is, after that every time I boot Ubuntu it does a file system check (so it says). During that check, Ctrl+C doesn't cancel the check. It shows no progress bar, only Ubuntu's rotating 'buffering' animation. It has significantly increased my boot time.
I checked with `tune2fs`. I have changed `Maximum Mount Count` to `30` (previously it was `-1`) with `tune2fs -c 30` and set check interval to 1 month with`tune2fs -i 1m`, but the problem persists.

I have a dual boot with Ubuntu + Windows 10. I only resized Ubuntu partitions, NOT windows partitions, with gparted.

How can I get rid of this file system check?

EDIT: I am using Gigabyte NVMe SSD. `jounaltcl -b 0 /dev/nvme0n1p8` & `jounaltcl -b 0 /dev/nvme0n1p6` (my 2 ubuntu ext4 partitions) have 1 yellow 'warning': `nvme nvme0: missing or invalid SUBNQN field.`

Comment: Do not cancel the check but have it run to completion. If after that, the system continues to perform full checks each time, then there may be a hardware issue.

Comment: I have let the check run to completion, multiple times. It didn't work. What kind of hardware issue are you talking about?

Comment: Hard drive or hard drive controller that could be failing.

Comment: @vanadium, is there anything I can do about it? How sure are you that it's a hardware issue? I don't want to poke around unnecessarily.

Comment: I am not sure of course, but I would account for this as a serious possibility. Hardware issues, if any, may reveal themselves through red messages in the output of `dmesg`.

Comment: `sudo journalctl -b 0 /dev/sdX` (`sdX` is the drive) will show log messages involving `/dev/sdX` for the current boot. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Read `man smartctl` to see how to get more data about the drive.

Comment: @vanadium, ```ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.GPP2.PTXH.RHUB.POT5._PLD due to previous error (AE_AML_UNINITIALIZED_ELEMENT) (20190816/psparse-529)``` 14 of these errors and ```[   36.456462] nvidia-gpu 0000:09:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   36.456467] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
[   36.456469] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
``` these are the errors that are shown for ```dmesg```

Comment: @waltinator, ```sudo journalctl -b 0 /dev/nvme0n1p(8/6)``` have 1 yellow warning: ```nvme nvme0: missing or invalid SUBNQN field.``` What is it and what can I do about it?

Comment: @waltinator, ```No manual entry for smartctl```

Comment: 2Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your  the whole story.

Comment: @waltinator, no need to get testy. I have edited my question with additional info.